# wkhtmltopdf doesn't save input value

Tags: jquery, wkhtmltopdf

The page contains drop down list, text input, date. When i run `wkhtmltopdf` it saves blank. What would be the work around to this. And how can it be save like download. And where can i see the debug result? Thanks.

testpdf.php

```
echo shell_exec("C:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe http://localhost/bigkpo/po/select.php --debug-javascript C:\Taopix\MediaAlbumWeb\webroot\bigkpo\PO\pdf\PO.pdf");
```

jquery on submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //disable not 1st select
    $("#description").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#orientation").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#page").attr("disabled","disabled");

        //start----------------------compny
        $("select#company").change(function()
            {
            $("#description").empty();
            $("#description").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id = $("#company option:selected").attr('value');
                        $.post("./includes/select_type.php", {id:id}, 
                        function(data0){
                        $("#description").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#description").html(data0);
                        });
                        });

        //start----------------------page
        $("#description").change(function()
            {
            $("#page").empty();
            $("#page").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id2 = $("#description option:selected").attr('value');
                        $.post("./includes/select_producprice_n_showpage.php", {id2:id2},
                        function(data1){
                        $("#page").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#page").html(data1);

                        //show price---------------------------
                        $("#productPrice").html(data1);
                        $("#productPrice2").html(data1);
                        });
                        });

        //start----------------------orientation
        $("#page").change(function()
            {
            $("#orientation").empty();
            $("#orientation").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            var id3 = $("#page option:selected").attr('value');
                        $.post("./includes/select_pageprice_n_showrientation.php", {id3:id3},
                        function(data2){
                        $("#orientation").removeAttr("disabled");
                        $("#orientation").html(data2);

                        //show insidepagePrice-----------------
                        $("#insidepagePrice").html(data2);
                        $("#insidepagePrice2").html(data2);
                        });

                        var quantity = $("#qty").val();
                        var id2 = $("#description option:selected").attr('value');
                        $.post("./includes/select_total.php", {id2: id2, id3: id3, quantity:quantity},
                        function(data3){

                        //computation------------------------------
                        $("#total").html(data3);
                        var vat = Math.round(data3 / 1.12 * 0.12).toFixed(2);
                        $("#vat").html(vat);
                        $("#sub").html(data3 - vat);
                        });
                        });


        $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
            var side = $("#select_form").html();
            console.log(side);
            });
            });
```

php form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php include "./includes/select.class.php"; ?>

    <div id="wraper">

    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="contenthead">
            <img src="css/img/kdi.jpg" align="left" /> 
            <h1> PURCHASE <br> ORDER </h1>
            <table align="right">
                <tr>
                <td><b> Date: </b>  </td> <td>&nbsp; <?php echo date('jS \of F Y'); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><b> Ref Number: </b> </td> <td> &nbsp; 271 </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="contentbody">
        <form id="select_form" action="testpdf.php" method="post">

            <table width="900px">
            <thead>
                <tr align="left">
                    <th class="boldlabel" colspan="3"> Company Name:<br>
                            <select id="company">
                                <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
                            </select>
                    </th>
                    <th class="boldlabel" colspan="2"> <b>  Ship to:    </b> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="110" align="center" class="boldlabel"> QTY </td>
                    <td width="110" align="center" class="boldlabel"> UOM </td>
                    <td width="456" align="center" class="boldlabel"> Description </td>
                    <td width="100" align="center" class="boldlabel"> UNIT PRICE </td>
                    <td width="100" align="center" class="boldlabel"> TOTAL </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr class="top row">
                    <td width="100" align="center"> <input id="qty" type="text" name="qty" style="width: 50px; text-align:center"  align="middle"> </td>
                    <td align="center"> <select>
                                            <option> PC </option>
                                            <option> BOX</option>
                                            <option> PACK</option>
                                        </select>
                                        </td>
                    <td align="left">   <select id="description"></select>  </td>
                    <td align="center"> <label id="productPrice"></label>   </td>
                    <td align="center"> <label id="productPrice2"></label>  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="side">
                    <td align="center">&nbsp;   </td>
                    <td align="center">&nbsp;   </td>
                    <td align="left">   <select id="page"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center"> <label id="insidepagePrice"></label>    </td>
                    <td align="center"> <label id="insidepagePrice2"></label>   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="side">
                    <td align="center">&nbsp;   </td>
                    <td align="center">&nbsp;   </td>
                    <td align="left">  <select id="orientation"></select>   </td>
                    <td align="center">         </td>
                    <td align="center">         </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="bottom row">
                    <td align="center">&nbsp;   </td>
                    <td align="center">&nbsp;   </td>
                    <td align="center">         </td>
                    <td align="center">         </td>
                    <td align="center">         </td>
                </tr>

                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;  </td>
                    <td class="leftfoot" align="left"> <b> subtotal </b></td>
                    <td class="rightfoot" align="center"> <label id="sub"></label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;  </td>
                    <td class="leftfoot" align="left"><b> 12% VAT </b></td><br />
                    <td class="rightfoot" align="center">  <label id="vat"> </label> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;  </td>
                    <td class="buttomleftfoot" align="left"> <b> Total Amount </b></td>
                    <td class="buttomrightfoot" align="center"> <label id="total"> </label> </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="contentfoot">
            <table width="900px">
            <tr>
            <td width="194"> Requested by: <br> <input type="text" name="qty" style="width: 200px; text-decoration:underline"  align="middle"> </td>
            <td width="476">&nbsp;  </td>
            <td width="214"> Noted by: <br> _____________________ </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="1">&nbsp;  </td>

                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="    Print    ">
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" value="  Submit  " name="submit"/>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/process.js"> </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following settings to allow JavaScript content to be rendered.

```
--enable-javascript
--javascript-delay
```

See the documentation for more options

https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/Usage

You should be able to just add the parameters to the shell_exec command like this
Also try putting all parameters on one line and adding in the extension

```
echo shell_exec("C:\Taopix\MediaAlbumWeb\webroot\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe http://localhost/bigkpo/po/select.php C:\Taopix\MediaAlbumWeb\webroot\pdf\google.pdf --enable-javascript --javascript-delay 500");
```

This will enable javascript and wait 500 milliseconds before creating a screen capture.
You can add `--debug-javascript` in order to get debug output about what might go wrong on the page.

**Update:**
From what i can deduce from your code is that you want to make a print screen in order to create some sort of receipt from the currently selected values by the user. 
You will not be able to create a screenshot from the page in the browser that the user is displaying, this is not how wkhtmltopdf works.

You will need to store the values the user selected and then rebuild the page entirely server side or provide automation on the client side to populate the fields so that wkhtmltopdf can create a proper screenshot, this requires some significant re-factoring. I can not help you any further.

Comment: yes, almost all are from jquery. Is there a work around to this? how to export page as pdf or jpg? T_T

Comment: we're can i use or add that parameter? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: sorry for late response, i read the documentation and it's to long ;(. tried your `--enable-javascript --javascript-delay 500` don't have an output sorry.

Comment: You can debug where stuff is going wrong using `--debug-javascript` The documentation is a valuable resource, you don't have to read all of it but i'm certain that it can help you to fix your problem. Also try the new command i have updated in my question.

Comment: I think your `--enable-javascript --javascript-delay 500` is right. And the problem here is my content. how can i use `--debug-javascript`?

Comment: If you specify `--debug-javascript` then shell_exec should return the relevant messages. It might be useful to run wkhtmltopdf on your command line for debugging purposes.

Comment: where can I see the debug? for example in jquery console.log can be see at browser/console. thanks

Comment: The return value of shell_exec will contain all output, including the debug info.
Alternativly, Open a cmd.exe console on windows or a bash console on linux  and type in the wkhtmltopdf command with the parameters, this should give you all output as well.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Willem, that will be very handy. Now i got `Error: Failed loading page file:///C:/Taopix/MediaAlbumWeb/webroot/pdf/google.pdf` when adding `--enable-javascript --javascript-delay 500` but without `--enable-javascript --javascript-delay 500` it's working. Do you have an idea why? Thank you very much!

Comment: got it `wkhtmltopdf [GLOBAL OPTION]... [OBJECT]... <output file>` but still no value or data in dropdown list and text field.

Comment: you can now add `console.log(value)` calls inside your javascript code to debug where stuff is going wrong. It should show up in the output code. add your JavaScript output in your question so other people can evaluate.

Comment: Hi Willem, i update the question above. Thank you very much, \m/

Comment: clearly you are misunderstanding how wkhtmltopdf or javascript works, i need you to post the entire page in your question that you want to generate a pdf from, including all php and jquery code. This is the only way that i will be able to assist any further.

Comment: Hi Willem please bare with me, updated the question above. All i want to do is save pdf after button pressed.

Comment: I can save to PDF but there's nothing on input field and drop down list. I don't know if my data is in server side or client side.

Comment: updated my question, please do not make any further comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a bit of an effort to make sure that you can convert the whole page WITH the contents in the form. You'd actually have to do some server-side processing to regenerate the page with the content and THEN pass is to wkhtmltopdf.

It's probably a lot less work to just use a web service and let your visitor click a link that returns the PDF. Have a look at [pdfmyform](http://www.pdfmyform.com)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to DOM documents and select statements, you generally have to fiddle the data, yourself.

My final solution was to compare the intended value to all available `<option>` values and then setAttribute("selected", true) ...

That was the only way I was able to solve this problem (in PHP).